# What make and model is this MTB with no decal (pictured)?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike, vintage

[image]

[image]

My second hand MTB frame has no decal on it. To me it looks like a downhill frame. I was told it's an Orange but now that I look at it I don't know how to tell. The serial number is JSG0111.

Comment: a photo would help

Comment: Click "edit" and immediately above the editing area there's a row of different buttons. Click the rectangle picture button to add an image.

Comment: here is A Picture of My Bike and also My Serial No JSG0111

Comment: If there is a decal or badge on the headtube a picture or description of that would be the most useful in identifying the make of your frame.

Comment: Fairly generic.  A close-up of the shocks (and the emblem on them) might trigger a memory somewhere, though.  (Not what I'd call "vintage", BTW.)

Comment: This bike is clearly not factory spec anymore. The frame was most likely sandblasted; front fork doesn't have brake caliper at all and supports disc brakes only, while frame is rim-only, and same goes for wheels. It's just a frankenbike with low level components. The best bet to know frame manufacturer is to contact person who did modifications. I wouldn't bother in your place by these details, missing front brake is more important.

Comment: So it's just a Cheap Frame then

Comment: The plate on the down tube just behead the head tube looks interesting.

Comment: I have a hunch... are the brakes Promax?

Comment: The only Orange it could possibly be is a Gringo, but I'm pretty sure they all had wishbone stays and round (cylindrical) top tubes.

Answer (score 1):

I locked in your FORK, but your frame could most likely be from the 1990's

SR Suntour XCM V3 Coil 26" Fork (2011)

Item Number:    100079607
Manufacturer:
Suntour
ItemNo  100079607
Color   Black
Fork Model  XCM V3 coil QR-V/D fork 100mm (1" thrd-150mm NLA>
Steerer Tube    1" Threaded
Front Axle Type 9x100mm quick-release
Spring Type Coil
Brake Type  rim + disc (6" PM)

Comment: that's aluminium.. are you sure it's from 1990s? All I know from the 1990s frame are steel.

Comment: @NhânLê - Cannondale, Klein, Pace... (not that this is any of those, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a trek to me the the gusset on the bottom of the frame that is X shaped is like trek does

Comment: You could make this a better answer by including a picture of a Trek that's close in order to show how it is similar.