# my Bike Make & Model

Tags: mountain-bike

Here's Some Pics Of Forks SR Suntour V3s
!

---

![enter image description ![

[image: SR Suntour XCM V3]

Comment: I doubt it is a specialized, given that they're normally plastered with the S or Specialized. Also, specialized serial numbers don't start with JSG.

Comment: Here is Some Pictures Of My Suspension Forks There SR Suntour V3s

Comment: @MarkSimpson It looks like you've posted two different versions of this question. Please use the other one since this one has been marked as a duplicate. http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/28988/what-make-and-model-is-this-mtb-with-no-decal-pictured